# Restricted async operation 'setTimeOut' in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am getting 'Restricted async operation 'setTimeOut' in LWC' error in VS Code when I use `setTimeOut` in `connectedCallback`.

`.html file`

```
<template>
<div class="wrapper">
<header class="header" if:true={ready} >Available Bikes for {name}</header>
</div>
</template>
```

`.js file`

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class Selector extends LightningElement {
@track
ready = false;
connectedCallback() {
   setTimeout(() => {
       this.ready = true;
   }, 3000);
}
```

What is the alternative to perform any action after certain time in LWC?

Comment: The linter flags async patterns because overuse leads to code that is difficult to maintain and there is almost always a better way to do it. Would you mind sharing what you are trying to do?

Comment: I was basically experimenting with `connectedCallback()` and came to this error and could not find the exact reason behind this. I think I was trying display some content once the page loads which can be achieved with `renederedCallback()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Settimeout is generally restricted for LWC as there are other ways to implement the functionality. More information [here](https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc/blob/master/docs/rules/no-async-operation.md)

If you still need to use you can disable es-linting by adding the below before your settimeout line

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-operation

renderedCallback() {
   if(!this.ready)
   this.ready == true;
}
```

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_rendered)

> Due to mutations, a component is usually rendered many times during
>   its lifespan in an application. To you use this hook to perform a
>   one-time operation, use a private boolean property like  hasRendered
>   to track whether renderedCallback() has been executed. The first time
>   renderedCallback() executes, perform the one-time operation and set
>   hasRendered = true. If  hasRendered = true, don’t perform the
>   operation.

Comment: I tried with `renderedCallback` and `ready` gets set to `true` once page gets rendered which is fine. However, on inspect I found that `renderedCallback` is getting called multiple times (in this case 3 times).

Comment: so stop it by checking if ready is true dont set it again. This has been called out in the documentation as well. have updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: got it ! Thanks!

Comment: what if there is legit reason for a fix wait , the hook would work then would it, also when I tried to ignore the lint using the comment you suggested I get:
Inline rule disablement not allowed.

Comment: Currently, this seems to be triggering a false positive in Salesforce Scanner : https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner/issues/1161