# LWC: Set a timer for the invocation of a method

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to hide a component 5 seconds after a certain event occurs. I was thinking about using `setTimeout()` but it appears that it is restricted in LWC(read [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261416/restricted-async-operation-settimeout-in-lwc) and [here](https://github.com/salesforce/eslint-plugin-lwc/blob/master/docs/rules/no-async-operation.md)).

Do I absolutely have to disable `es-linting` in order to fulfill my requirement? Is there something that LWC provides out of the box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

those rules have nothing to do with blocked functionalities - they will still work even if highlighted in the editor / running linter. They are meant to highlight common practices / code style etc. to you - not more.

If it annoys you you can disable those hints eiter globally or for specific lines via inline comments or configuration in the .eslintrc.json => the linter can be kept on.

See eslint docs [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) for details.

E. g. putting `/* eslint-disable @lwc/lwc/no-async-operation */` on top of your file would remove the warning for the whole file while disabling the rule in the eslintrc.json would disable it globally for the all lwcs in your workspace.